# ComboBox binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, combobox

I've got a simple question, I've got a `ComboBox` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a relatively expensive service call.

If I have the `ComboBox` in question disabled will the binding still fire? If so what I can I do to ensure that the expensive call is only made when it really needs to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to at least consider modifying the template for the `ComboBox` so that it uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, at least, as long as your service call fetches items one at a time.  See [this](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/12/15/wpf-using-a-virtualizingstackpanel-to-improve-combobox-performance.aspx) for a pretty good discussion of the issues.

**Edit**

To answer your actual question:  no, disabling the `ComboBox` doesn't stop it from populating its items.  I determined this by implementing a collection class, binding a `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` to an instance of it, and watching it service its method calls.  Its items get retrieved if the `ComboBox` is enabled.  They even get retrieved if its `Visibility` is `Collapsed`.  I'm pretty surprised; that's not what I would have expected at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'll take a look at the article - looks good.
Thanks again.